# How can i eliminate duplicate data when joining 2 queries via union?

Tags: mysql

i have 2 queries that pull same fields with only diff is what the subquery in the where clause returns.

first query pulls based on the code and insurance_group_name

```
SELECT 
  cpt_codes.code,
  ii.insurance_group_name,
  ii.insurance_group_id,
  CAST(AVG(dcc_total_view.allowedAmount) AS decimal(10, 2)) `AVG Allowed by Group Name`,
 CAST(AVG(rc_total_view.runningCollectedReceivedByProvider) AS decimal(10, 2)) `AVG Collected by Group Name`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT file_acceptance) AS `FAN`
FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
    ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
    ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN rc_total_view
    ON ds.payment_information_id = rc_total_view.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc_total_view
    ON ds.id = dcc_total_view.dos_id
WHERE (cpt_codes.code, ii.insurance_group_name) IN (SELECT 
    cpt_codes.code,
    ii.insurance_group_name  
  FROM ds
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
      ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
      ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
      ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
      ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
      ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
      ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  WHERE cs.status = 'Pending'
  AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
  AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
  OR dcc.rev_code = '0360'))
AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
OR dcc.rev_code = '0360')
AND  dcc_total_view.allowedAmount > 0
GROUP BY code ,insurance_group_name
```

this would return a line like this

| code | insurance_group_name | insurance_group_id | AVG Allowed by Group Name | AVG Collected by Group Name | FAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20553 | AE | 215825 | 1440.97 | 889.48 | DELA081518,MOLDGILR919,SHIC060618,MANS072718,DELA053018,DELS072518 |

the Second one pulls based on insurance_group_id

```
SELECT 
  cpt_codes.code,
  ii.insurance_group_name,
  ii.insurance_group_id,
  CAST(AVG(dcc_total_view.allowedAmount) AS decimal(10, 2)) `AVG Allowed by Group Name`,
 CAST(AVG(rc_total_view.runningCollectedReceivedByProvider) AS decimal(10, 2)) `AVG Collected by Group Name`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT file_acceptance) AS `FAN`
FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
    ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
    ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
    ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
    ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
    ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN rc_total_view
    ON ds.payment_information_id = rc_total_view.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc_total_view
    ON ds.id = dcc_total_view.dos_id
WHERE (cpt_codes.code, ii.insurance_group_id) IN (SELECT 
    cpt_codes.code,
    ii.insurance_group_id  
  FROM ds
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
      ON ds.dos_detail_id = dd.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ii
      ON ds.ii_id = ii.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dcc
      ON ds.id = dcc.dos_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cpt_codes
      ON dcc.cpt_id = cpt_codes.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN bi
      ON ds.billing_id = bi.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cs
      ON bi.claim_status = cs.id
  WHERE cs.status = 'Pending'
  AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
  AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
  OR dcc.rev_code = '0360'))
AND date_of_service BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2018/08/31'
AND (dcc.rev_code = '0490'
OR dcc.rev_code = '0360')
AND  dcc_total_view.allowedAmount > 0
GROUP BY code ,insurance_group_id
```

this would return a line like

| code | insurance_group_name | insurance_group_id | AVG Allowed by Group Name | AVG Collected by Group Name | FAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20553 | AE | 10198703100012 | 250.25 | 150.36 | MOLDGILR919 |

when doing union on these 2 i find some data is duplicated where the FAN # that the second query returns is included in the output from the first as you can see the FAN# is part of the ones that make up the results of the first script.
how can i join together the results of these 2 queries and make sure if the FAN# in the second is already included in results from the first for a given code (like 20553 in the example) then that row from the second will not be included in the final output ?
I hope i have included enough info and detail to help me out here, I really appreciate any help to figure this out.

Comment: not really so you have tow diffrent rows and how should the result look like excatly

Comment: thats my confusion, since the group ID doesnt directly coorelate to group name thats why im running for each, what i think i need to figure out is how can compare the FANs for each row returned if match returned then dont include that line from group_id query, maybe can i somehow join the queries together and then select on that with another where clause excluding where FAN from # included in FAN from First for given code ? just not sure how that would work

Comment: define for every column which value you want from the first or the second third, then group by code, or why not keep all and hold ahem in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Put the output of your  first statemen in a temporary table, lets name that `#temp1`, and the output of your second query in a temporary table named `#temp2`.

After that you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM #temp1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM #temp2
WHERE code NOT IN (SELECT code FROM #temp1)
```

EDIT:  Because of the FAN problem..

I think you should change your queries, in this way:
Do not use GROUP_CONCAT(...) to combine the results of different FAN's in one row, and add `file_acceptance` to the GROUP BY-clause

This way you will get indivdual records for every FAN, annd, after the `UNION ALL` you can GROUP_CONCAT() then again.

This might need some more think/tweak work because of the AVG() fields....

Comment: that might be it , i will give that a shot thanks

Comment: ok i was able to setup 2 temp tables one for each query and run the union all which then gives me all the results of the 2. using the 2 rows of output from original as example, i want to remove the rows where if the code# match, and group name matches, like above where code is 20553 and group name is AE but the FAN#s of the one from the second query is already included in the output of the first query how do we remove that line ?

Comment: Added a comment because of this FAN problem.